# Spring Boot Hibernate Constraint Validator

Tags: json, spring-boot, gson, hibernate-validator

I would like to make a field validation without persisting data by using Spring Boot and Hibernate Validator.

```
public class RoomDto {

    private long id;

    @Expose
    private int beds;

    @Expose
    private double size;

    @Expose
    @NotNull
    private String flatBasicStringDto;
}
```

I am parsing a DTO from JSON by using GSON:

```
RoomDto guestRoom = this.jsonParser.read(RoomDto.class, "/files/input/room.json");
```

I would like to get an error when flatBasicStringDto is missing in the JSON file.

I have tried many configurations but nothing works so far.

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist=javax.validation.groups.Default
```

Any ideas how to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method level validation using @valid annotation. However, you need your DI container to hook in with the validation framework. A comprehensive example using spring is at http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/.

If you dont want to use a DI containter, you can use something like this to get the validation errors:

```
 ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
 Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
 Set<ConstraintViolation<RoomDto>> errors = validator.validate(guestRoom);
```

Comment: Splendid answer! Both suggestions work fine. It seems that I've been using a wrong approach. Thank you!